# ::value はなんですか？

Tags: c++

下記コードの `::value` はなんでしょうか？
コンパイル時にテンプレートが処理されるときに、値が決定する特殊な変数のようなものでしょうか？
文法的になにか名称はありますか？

おそらく自分で似たような用法のテンプレートを自作するときは、value でなくて、名前はなんでもよいと推測しているのですが、valueでないといけないなどのルールはありますか？

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  std::array<int, 3> a = { 1, 2, 3};

  auto size = std::tuple_size<decltype(a)>::value;

  std::cout << size;
  return 0;
}
```

---

追記：
コメントで紹介いただいた
[std::tuple_sizeクラスの説明書](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/array/array/tuple_size.html) や　[std::tuple_size](https://cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/tuple_size/)　や [tuple_size クラス](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/standard-library/tuple-size-class-tuple?view=msvc-170)
によると

- integral_constantの機能
- member constant
- 整数定数式であるメンバー value

と呼ばれているもののようですね。

結局どこを見ればいいのか、不明ですが（おそらく公式はISOなのでカジュアルに見れない？）、「integral_constantの機能」で深掘りして、さらに見てみると下記に辿り着きました。

https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/type_traits/integral_constant.html
にある通り、`integral_constant` 構造体のメンバー変数であるvalueという認識でよいのでしょうか？

`static constexpr` とすれば、テンプレートの評価時に定数を入れることができる用法（テクニック）があるということですかね。

質問を整理すると（整理というには強引ですが）

- この value は構造体のメンバー変数であっているか？
- こんな用法が使えるのは `static constexpr` のおかげか？

という感じになりそうです。（おそらく合っていそうな気はしますが、あくまで推測です）

Comment: 何を知りたいのか今一不明ですが、std::tuple_sizeクラスの説明書を読まずに質問していますか？それとも[std::tuple_sizeクラスの説明書](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/array/array/tuple_size.html)を読んだ上での質問でしょうか？前者ならまず説明書を読んで質問内容を整理しください。

Comment: この辺の仕様？解説？記事を見るとtuple_sizeクラスの仕様に定義されてるようですね。[std::tuple_size](https://cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/tuple_size/), [tuple_size クラス](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/standard-library/tuple-size-class-tuple?view=msvc-170) 自分でクラスを別に新たに作るなら何でも良いのかもしれません。

Comment: @alpha いただいた資料のおかげで、理解が深まりました。ほぼ自己解決になりそうですが、あまり自信がないので、質問を整理してみました。（整理というには少し強引ですが...）

Answer (score 3):

> おそらく自分で似たような用法のテンプレートを自作するときは、`value` でなくて、名前はなんでもよいと推測しているのですが、`value` でないといけないなどのルールはありますか？

C++標準ライブラリにおける名前付けの慣習として、あるクラステンプレート（メタ関数）が定数値を公開する場合は `value` を、型を公開する場合は `type` を用います。

> `integral_constant` 構造体のメンバー変数である`value`という認識でよいのでしょうか？
> この `value` は構造体のメンバー変数であっているか？

はい。正しい認識です。

---

> こんな用法が使えるのは `static constexpr` のおかげか？

この質問への答えは、半分YES／半分NOといったところでしょうか。

C++11以降では、クラスメンバとしてのコンパイル時定数は `static constexpr` を用いて定義されます。

C++11よりも古いC++言語でも、「クラスメンバにコンパイル時定数を定義する」ことは可能でした。当時は `static const` や [Enumハック](https://pknight.hatenablog.com/entry/20090802/1249211249) と呼ばれる技法が使われていました。